# Swift 4 - Parsing XML-File using struct to array

Tags: swift, xml

My first Swift App with XML parsing works. I want to clean the code. So I started a new project with the same app.

This is my struct

```
struct Bereich {
    var name = ""
    var wert = ""
    var status = ""
    var symbol = ""
}
```

XML Parser

```
class ParseXML: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    var eName : String = ""

    var vName : String = ""
    var vWert : String = ""
    var vStatus : String = ""
    var vSymbol : String = ""

    var xmlAsArray = [Bereich]()

    func startParsing(){
        getXMLDataFromServer()
    }

    func getXMLDataFromServer(){
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://*******************")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) in
            if data == nil {
                print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }

            let parser = XMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

        eName = elementName
        if elementName == "param"{
            print("Started parsing")
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

        let foundedChar = string.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

        switch eName {
        case "name": vName = foundedChar
        case "Wert": vWert = foundedChar
        case "Status": vStatus = foundedChar
        case "Symbol": vSymbol = foundedChar
        default: break
        }
    }
```

The code works until here

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if eName == "param"{
        var myBereich = Bereich()
        myBereich.name = vName
        myBereich.wert = vWert
        myBereich.status = vStatus
        myBereich.symbol = vSymbol
        xmlAsArray.append(myBereich)
    }

    print("Parsing ended")
}
```

It seems that this specific part of code isn't working. 
I can't figure it out why it isn't parsing the elements of the XML into the struct and the array.

**EDIT:**

I figured it out. It has to be "+=" to add each character found in the xml tags.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    let foundedChar = string.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    switch eName {
    case "name": vName += foundedChar
    case "Wert": vWert += foundedChar
    case "Status": vStatus += foundedChar
    case "Symbol": vSymbol += foundedChar
    default: break
    }

}
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not a very helpful explanation, please add some more info about how it fails and any error message you get. Also explain what you changed in the new version.

Comment: There are no errors.. that's the problem. The code starts to parse the file correctly but it doesn't save the parsed elements in the struct class. The difference between the old and the new version is that the new version should use a struct class. The old version saves the elements in different variables for each tag.

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Comment: Nitpicking but there is no such thing as a "struct class", it's either a struct or it's a class.

Comment: I forget to use the debugger every time. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Does your **EDIT** code really work for xml with multiple `param`s ? Or you have other fixes?

Comment: Yes. There are 7 param-tags in the XML and every param with its tags like "name",..., "status" are being added to the xmlAsArray-Array.